# Tkinter button function not working after compiling/bundling to standalone application

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a Python Tkinter application that works perfectly when running from the source code. However, after I compile it using PyInstaller (or any other bundling tool), the button functions seem to stop working. The application loads without errors, but clicking on the buttons doesn't trigger the intended actions. Could someone help me understand why the button functions are not working in the compiled standalone application?

i'm using python3 on Linux Redhat RHEL Server 8.8

this is my code :

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
import subprocess

# Set Variable afi_process is None
afi_process = None

# Define a Function Python

def open_file():
    win.openfile = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/mnt/res/_EXPLOITATION", title="Choose afi Files", filetypes=[("Text Files", "*.txt"), ("Afi Files", ".afi"), ("All Files",
 "*.*")])
    if win.openfile:
        text_box.delete(1.0, END)
        text_box.insert(END, win.openfile)
        buttonRunAfi.config(state=NORMAL)
    #print("eclrun --gpu ix", win.openfile)

#def run_command():
    #global process
    #process_ping = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "8.8.8.8"])

#def stop_command():
    #global process
    #if process_ping.poll() is not None:
        #process.terminate()

def run_afi():
    global runAfi
    runAfi = subprocess.Popen(["eclrun", "--gpu", "ix", win.openfile])

def stop_afi():
    global runAfi
    if win.openfile is not None:
        runAfi.kill()
    print("Terminating Process")

def frame_about():
    hide_frame()
    current_status.set("About")
    text.grid(row=0, column=0)


def frame_single():
    current_status.set("Home")
    hide_frame()
    button.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky="w")
    #buttonStop.grid()
    buttonRunAfi.grid(column=1, columnspan=2, row=5, sticky="w")
    buttonCancelAfi.grid(column=1,row=6, sticky="w")
    statusBar.grid(row=8, columnspan=8, sticky="w"+"e")
    text_box.grid(row=4, column=2)
    rbuttonsingle.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="w")
    rbuttoncoupling.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="w")

def hide_frame():
    text.grid_forget()
    button.grid_forget()
    #buttonStop.grid_forget()
    buttonRunAfi.grid_forget()
    buttonCancelAfi.grid_forget()
    rbuttonsingle.grid_forget()
    rbuttoncoupling.grid_forget()
    text_box.grid_forget()


# Root Box Windows
win = tk.Tk()
win.title("IX - Intersect Linux Launcher")
win.geometry("800x300")

# Configure row and column weight biar Responsive
for i in range(8):
    win.grid_rowconfigure(i, weight=1)

for j in range(8): # Adjust the range according to the number of columns
    win.grid_columnconfigure(j, weight=1)

# Text Box for Open file Variable
text_box = Text(win, bg="white", height=2, wrap=WORD)


# Create Menu Bar Variable
MenuBar = Menu(win)
win.config(menu=MenuBar)

# Create Menu Items Variable
Home = Menu(MenuBar)
MenuBar.add_cascade(label="Home", menu=Home)
Home.add_command(label="Home", command=frame_single)

About = Menu(MenuBar)
MenuBar.add_cascade(label="About", menu=About)
About.add_command(label="About", command=frame_about)

# Radio Button Variable
rbuttonsingle = Radiobutton(win, text="Running Single Model", value=1)
rbuttoncoupling = Radiobutton(win, text="Running Coupling Model", state=DISABLED, value=2)


# Status Bar Variable
current_status = StringVar()
statusBar = Label(win, textvariable=current_status, bd=2, relief="sunken", anchor=E)
text = Label(win, text="This tkinter GUI launcher is specifically designed to execute the '.afi intersect' command easily and efficiently. With an intuitive user interface, you can 
execute the command with just a single click of a button. Enjoy the convenience of running your command without having to remember the syntax or type it manually. Thank you for usin
g our launcher application! - Version : Beta 0.0.2", wraplength=500, justify="left")


#buttonStop = tk.Button(win, text="Stop Command", command=stop_command)
#buttonStop.pack(side="bottom", anchor="se")

# Button Variable
button = tk.Button(win, text="Open File", command=open_file, width=20, height=2)
buttonRunAfi = tk.Button(win, text="Run Afi File", command=run_afi, width=93, height=2, state=DISABLED)
buttonCancelAfi = tk.Button(win, text="Terminate Process", command=stop_afi, width=20, height=2)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please try to reduce the code to a [mcve]. If the problem is with a button running a command, we just need that one button, the code it is supposed to run, and enough extra to make it run.

Comment: If you print out something in those functions, did you get those messages when running the compiled executable (you need to compile it to a console application)?